# Move elastic IP between servers on AWS

Tags: amazon-ec2, ip

Can someone provide some CLI commands to move an Elastic IP between servers in AWS?  I have the AWS EC2 CLI command for associate/disassociate and it requires an association ID.  How do I get that?  As well, I have 2 NIC's in each server (instance)...how do I tell AWS to associate the Elastic IP with the right NIC?

Answer (score 0):

To allocate EIP to the ENI you will have to use `--network-interface-id` check this link for details

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/create-network-interface.html.

And you can get association ID for the EIP from the console check this screenshot.
[image]

Or you can achieve that from command line.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/describe-addresses.html

Comment: Could you provide the CLI commands for the above?  (This has to be fully scripted to work - and I'm also not clear if the allocation ID changes, if the association ID is the same as allocation ID, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

```
aws ec2 associate-address --region us-east-1 --allocation-id eipalloc-xxx --allow-reassociation --network-interface-id eni-xxx
```